# Why should heat transfer occur between infinitesimally small temperature difference in a reversible process?

Tags: thermodynamics

In thermodynamics, a reversible process is quasi static (because every point in the system should be in equilibrium to study the state properties and work done is maximum), but why should heat transfer occur between infinitesimally small temperature difference(why not between finite temperature difference)?

Comment: Because a reversible process consists of a continuous sequence of thermodynamic equilibrium states, and a system can not be at thermodynamic equilibrium if there are finite temperature gradients within the system.

Comment: But how can a finite temperature gradient affect the efficiency of the process.Wont the gradient die out after some time?

Comment: Suppose I have a hot body and an identical cold body, and I place them into direct contact with one another, allowing them to equilibrate spontaneously via transient heat conduction (automatically involving large finite transient temperature gradients).  How much work is done by this process?  What is the mechanical efficiency of this process?  Now I employ a working fluid between the two bodies and use a sequence of mini Carnot cycles to reversibly extract tiny amounts of heat from the hot body and transfer tiny amounts of  heat to the cold body in each cycle.  Any work now?

Comment: I think no work is done when heat transfer occurs by direct contact. When a Carnot engine is used to transfer heat reversibly, work is done .But if the temperature difference between the cold and the hot bodies is finite, how can we claim that the engine operates reversibly?(From whatever I learnt, I understood that for an engine to operate reversibly, the temperature difference between the source and the sink should be infinitesimally small)

Comment: So when you have isothermal expansion of an ideal gas, it can't be reversible (even with just a tiny difference in temperature between the reservoir and the gas)?

Comment: I think it can be reversible if there is no friction between the piston and the cylinder,during contraction the heat transfer between the system and surrounding should be in such a way that the temperature of the system does not change and I have learnt that the temperature difference between the system and the surrounding should be tiny for the process to be reversible.But I couldn't understand why the temperature difference matters.

Comment: If the reservoir is at a higher temperature than the average gas temperature, such that the gas temperature within the cylinder varies spatially during the expansion, will the force per unit area at the piston face be the same (even if the expansion is carried out quasi statically) as if the heat transfer were carried out reversibly (with only a slight difference between the reservoir and the gas temperatures)?  The pressure within the cylinder will depend on the temperature distribution within the cylinder.  The process will not take place isothermally.   The amount of work will be different.

Comment: I understand that if the temperature difference is large, heat transfer occurs at a faster rate. The molecules closer to the heat source will be initially at a higher temperature than those far from it.Thus the temperature varies both with time and position. So the process is not isothermal. Even if the system attains equilibrium after some time, the average temperature will be higher than what it initially was.So some amount of energy will be spent to rise the temperature of the system(internal energy).So the work done will be lower initially.But won't the increased energy be used to do work?

Comment: Please suggest me some good books to understand thermodynamics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This all depends on precisely what the temperature boundary condition is at the surface of the cylinder.  We can solve the transient differential heat balance equations within the cylinder as a function of time, and predict the pressure and the work done by the gas (even if the work is close to quasi static).  This is a do-able calculation.  But we would need to specify the problem precisely, and be sure that we are comparing apples with apples.  As far as good thermodynamics books, I highly recommend "Fundamentals of Engineering Thermodynamics," by Moran et al.  I particularly like their alternative treatment of the 2nd law of thermodynamics.